# cannot instantiate type of array list

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm pretty new at Java and need answer quick so don't judge if I haven't searched enough. So i have class Antena and trying to make Controller class and i can't make array list instance. Code is unfinished. Can someone solve this? :D
This is controller class:

```
package paket;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label; 
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser; 
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;

public class KontrolaAntene implements Initializable {
private List<Antena> antene= new ArrayList<Antena>();
private int broj;

@FXML
private Button btnIspisi;
@FXML
private Button btnIzlaz;
@FXML
private TextArea taIspis;
@FXML
private TextArea taIspis_izlaz;
@FXML
private Label label1;
@FXML
private Label label2;
@FXML
private Label label3;
@FXML
private TextField tfx;
@FXML
private TextField tfy;

@FXML
void ispisi(ActionEvent event){
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Izaberi datoteku");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("Text files","*.txt"),
            new ExtensionFilter("All files","*.txt")
            );

    String pocetakputanja = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File pocetak = new File(pocetakputanja);

    if(!pocetak.canRead())
    {
        pocetak = new File("C:/");
    }

    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(pocetak);

    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(TestAntene.mainStage);

    if(selectedFile == null || selectedFile.getName()!="antene.txt"){
        taIspis.setText("Datoteka antene.txt nije izabrana");
    }
    else{
        taIspis.setText("");
        ispisiFajl(selectedFile);
    }


    }

void ispisiFajl(File selectedFile){
    antene.clear();
    Path put = Paths.get(selectedFile.getPath());
    Charset kod = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(put, kod.name());
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String linija = sc.nextLine();
        String tip = linija.substring(0,linija.indexOf(":")).trim();
        String delovi[]= linija.substring(linija.indexOf(":") + 1,
                    linija.length()).split(", ");
        if(tip == "K"){
        //THIS LINE IS A PROBLEM!
            Antena nova = new Antena(Integer.parseInt(delovi[1].trim()),
                    Integer.parseInt(delovi[1].trim()),Integer.parseInt(delovi[1].trim()));
        }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        taIspis.setText("Datoteka antene.txt nije izabrana");
    }
   }

@FXML
void ispisi_izlaz(ActionEvent event){
    taIspis_izlaz.appendText("Broj antena koje pokrivaju zadato mesto je "+broj);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

This is class Antena:

package paket;

public abstract class Antena {

```
public int x;
public int y;
public int Domet1;
public int Domet2;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public int getDomet1() {
    return Domet1;
}
public void setDomet1(int domet1) {
    Domet1 = domet1;
}
public int getDomet2() {
    return Domet2;
}
public void setDomet2(int domet2) {
    Domet2 = domet2;
}
public Antena(int x, int y, int domet1, int domet2) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    Domet1 = domet1;
    Domet2 = domet2;
}   

boolean uDometu(int x, int y)
{

    double rastojanje;
    int x2 = getX();
    int y2 = getY();
    int domet1= getDomet1();
    int domet2= getDomet2();
    if(getDomet2() == 0){
        rastojanje= Math.sqrt((y-y2)*(y-y2)+(x-x2)*(x-x2));
        if((double)getDomet1() >= rastojanje)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
      if((x2==x && y2+domet2>y)||
         (x2==x && y2-domet2<y)||
         (x2+domet1>x && y2==y)||
         (x2-domet1<x && y2==y)){ return true;}
      else if((x2+domet1>=x && y2+domet1>=y)||
              (x2-domet1<=x && y2+domet1<=y)||
              (x2+domet1<=x && y2+domet1>=y)||
              (x2+domet1>=x && y2+domet1<=y))
                {return true;}
      else  return false;
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: What is the output when you try to run your code?

Comment: I didn't finish the task, so i didn't ran code.

Comment: Because you `Antena` class is abstract. You can't create instance of abstract class. Make `Antena` non-abstract, or create another non-abstract class that inherits from `Antena`

Comment: Error says : Cannot instantiate the type Antena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be comparing `String`(s) correctly, and you can't instantiate an `abstract` class. Options<sup>1</sup>,

1. Remove `abstract` from `Antenna`, or
2. Create a *concrete* subclass and *instantiate* that subclass

Something like

```
if (tip.equals("K")) { // == "K"){
    Antenna nova = new Antenna(Integer.parseInt(delovi[1].trim()), // ...
```

And remember to then change "`Antena`" like

```
public class Antenna { // <-- Not abstract
```

<sup>1<sub>I have also corrected the spelling of *antenna*.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in the line you have marked :

1. `Antena` is and abstract class and cannot be instantiated. That's a very fundamental feature of abstract classes that are meant to be inherited from. You should subclass `Antena` or make non-abstract
2. You are calling the constructor of `Antena` and you are passing 3 integers as arguments. But the only constructor for `Antena` takes 4 arguments of type `int`

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class and cannot be instantiated and antena is a abstract type.So remove the abstract keyword and it will work.